# Is there a way to change input type="text" to "date" using CSS only?

Tags: css, input, types

I'd like to replace though CSS the type of an input from input type="text" to input type="date". Does it possible?
Thanks

Comment: no not possible

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do? more details please...

Answer (score 9):

No.

CSS is a presentation language. It cannot be used to alter the semantics and structure of a document.

The closest you could come would be to determine which if a file and date input were visible in the document.

Answer (score 1):

You may only change appearance of elements (not real type) by css3 `appearance` property. For example some text element into element button:

```
span
{
    -moz-appearance:button;
    -webkit-appearance:button;
    appearance:button;
}
```

But list of possible values is limited. Still not chance to change `input type="text` into `input type="date"`.

Answer (score 0):

(Late for you, but could be useful for somebody else)
I had to do the same for the mobile version of my website. I created 2 forms, one for big resolution screens and other for mobile. After the resolution becomes less than 600px width I hide the 1 form and display the 2nd (the second one is with changed types).