# Change input type in stylesheet

Tags: html, css, input

I have an Input defined as followed:

```
<input name="Passwd-Input" class="pxBase-Input-Text" id="Passwd-Input" type="text">
```

Now I want to Change the "type" form text to Password in my Stylesheet.

I can adress the Input by ID

Now I search a Solution like:

```
#Passwd-Input{type:password;}
```

Is it possible to Change the type in Stylesheet and how does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change html input type by JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093992/change-html-input-type-by-js)

Comment: Seems like it is not possible, check this out ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383182/is-there-a-way-to-change-input-type-text-to-date-using-css-only

Comment: TL​​;​​D​​R​​:​​ ​​N​​o​​.​​

Comment: "stylesheet" wont change the control behavior, they are there to change their appearance

Comment: @Thangadurai Sure, like change the font family to something containing only dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the input value to dots(password) value like `input[type=password]`, you can use `-webkit-text-security: disc`

> *Note: only for `-webkit-` browsers..*

```css
.pwd {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input class="pwd" type="text" value="Hello">
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, correct me if im wrong but CSS is not really a Language per se. It is kind of a declarative Language.

Thats why you will not be able to change a HTML Attribute in CSS.

But if you are interested in a JS Solution, [here it goes.](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/pLWKMa)

You just call your Function on Button-Click.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showPW()">Show Password
```