# How does one set HTML "Button" type via CSS only?

Tags: html, css, button, types, factoring

There are three types of buttons in HTML5:
`<button type="button" ...>`,
`<button type="submit" ...>`, and
`<button type="reset" ...>`
We'd prefer to use CSS classes to set the type to keep the HTML compact, but I haven't been able to figure out how. Is this related to question #[16383182](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383182/is-there-a-way-to-change-input-type-text-to-date-using-css-only)?

Comment: this is no CSS , this is what they are. However, submit is the default behavior of a button . You cam omit that one ;)

Comment: CSS can't set or change the type, only the appearance

Comment: So far as I know, it is impossible to change type via CSS.

Comment: Okay, it looks like I'm out of luck on this. Thanks! Perhaps this and #16383182 can be merged so it's clear to readers & search engines it applies to both INPUT and BUTTON tags.